# Creating a compressed (or zipped) folder

Tags: vba, vb6

Is there a way to programmatically create a compressed folder in Windows? I can't see a way to do this using the FileSystemObject (although there is the 'Compressed' attribute).

I've seen zip dll's but I'd prefer to avoid having to re-distribute a dll if possible. Windows XP natively supports compressed folders after all.

Comment: See the following question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118547/creating-a-zip-file-on-windows-xp2003-in-cc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118547/creating-a-zip-file-on-windows-xp2003-in-cc).

Comment: Duplicate question, see [Windows built-in ZIP compression script-able?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/windows-built-in-zip-compression-script-able#124775) I also answered the question there with some sample code and a few links: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/windows-built-in-zip-compression-script-able#124775>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the following links:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpzip.htm

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1383147&SiteID=1

Stripping the important parts from the [first link](http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpzip.htm)  example may prove to be sufficient.

```
Sub NewZip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub

Function Split97(sStr As Variant, sdelim As String) As Variant
'Tom Ogilvy
    Split97 = Evaluate("{""" & _
                       Application.Substitute(sStr, sdelim, """,""") & """}")
End Function

Sub Zip_File_Or_Files()
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String, sFName As String
    Dim oApp As Object, iCtr As Long, I As Integer
    Dim FName, vArr, FileNameZip

    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"

    'Browse to the file(s), use the Ctrl key to select more files
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select the files you want to zip")
    If IsArray(FName) = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        I = 0
        For iCtr = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            vArr = Split97(FName(iCtr), "\")
            sFName = vArr(UBound(vArr))
            If bIsBookOpen(sFName) Then
                MsgBox "You can't zip a file that is open!" & vbLf & _
                       "Please close it and try again: " & FName(iCtr)
            Else
                'Copy the file to the compressed folder
                I = I + 1
                oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FName(iCtr)

                'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
                On Error Resume Next
                Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = I
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                Loop
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next iCtr

        MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i believe this fails if items are inside folders. If the source folder contains 20 items, it's namespace will report 20, but the zip namespace will still report just 1 item-- the folder.