# How to create zip file in Nsis

Tags: nsis

is there a possibility to create a ZIP file, which contains all of my to be installed files, during my installation (at runtime). I need this for my deployment installation of our software. Ive seen that the ZipDLL plugin can only extract files, is there a plugin or DLL witch can zipping files?

Answer (score 0):

[Some people claim that `SHFileOperation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118547/creating-a-zip-file-on-windows-xp-2003-in-c-c/118606) can do it [while others say no](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/Wh0Imc30cKs). The NSIS `CopyFiles` instruction uses `SHFileOperation` but I could not get it to add files to an existing empty .zip file.

You could try going down the [shell CopyHere](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176633.aspx) (COM or scripting) rabbit hole but it is not ideal since you cannot really wait for the operation to finish.

The best solution would be to write your own custom plug-in but if you cannot do that then I would recommend that you just bundle and call the command line version of [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/).